# Es posible hacer llamadas http sincronas o poder seguir una secuencia de llamadas http en Ionic y Angular

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una App con Ionic y Angular, pero al llamar a un API WEB tengo problemas porque al ser las llamadas asincronas no consigo que se ejecuten en el orden que yo quiero las llamadas al API WEB.

En concreto en app.component tengo la primera llamada al API WEB

```
 initializeApp(){
    this.servicioClikear.login().subscribe()
 }
```

y en una pagina tengo la segunda llamada al API WEB

```
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.servicioClikear.obtenerTodasNoticias().subscribe();
  }
```

El codigo del servicio que tiene las llamadas al API WEB es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClikearService {

  constructor(private  httpClient: HttpClient) {  }


  public  obtenerTodasNoticias(): Observable<any> {

      return  this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:43000/api/noticias');

  }

  public login(): Observable<any> {

    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:43000/api/login');

  }

}
```

La ejecucion secuencial que sigo al depurar el codigo es:

1. se ejecuta initializeApp() y por tanto se subscribe a la llamada al API WEB para logarse pero aunque me he subscrito al Observable no llega a llamar al API

   ```
   initializeApp(){

     this.servicioClikear.login().subscribe()

   }
   ```
2. entra en la pagina y se ejecuta ionViewWillEnter() de manera que se subscribe al observable y si que ejecuta la llamada al API WEB

   ```
   ionViewWillEnter(){

     this.servicioClikear.obtenerTodasNoticias().subscribe();

   }
   ```
3. Una vez realizada la llamada al API WEB para obtener Noticias `this.servicioClikear.obtenerTodasNoticias().subscribe()` entonces ya si se ejecuta la llamada al API WEB para hacer login

   ```
   this.servicioClikear.login().subscribe()
   ```

Y aqui viene mi pregunta, porque siempre se ejecuta antes la segunda llamada al API WEB en lugar de ejecutarse la primera llamada al API WEB ?

Ya se que las llamadas al API WEB son asincronas, pero existe alguna manera de asegurarme que no se ejecuta la segunda llamada al API WEB hasta que no se haya ejecutado la primera ?

Muchas gracias y cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida.

Comment: haz una llamada, espera una respuesta y entonces, dentro de la función que le pases a subscribe, realiza la segunda llamada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar utilizar el `async` y `await`, convirtiendo tus observables en promesas.

```
async login(): Promise<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:43000/api/login').toPromise();
}
```

```
initializeApp(){
  //const response = await this.servicioClikear.login();
  await this.servicioClikear.login();
}
```